# React cannot read properties of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to fetch data from a movie Api. I have added ternery operator to stop page loading before useEffect is done but still getting *Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toString')*, and have tried a setLoading state but doesn't help.

```
import axios from 'axios'

import MovieCard from '../components/MovieCard'
const Home = () => {
    const [movieData, getMovieData ] = useState(null)

    const getAllMoviesData = () => {
        axios.get(process.env.REACT_APP_MOVIES_URL)
            .then((res) => {
                const result = res.data.results
                getMovieData(result)
                console.log(result)
            })
            .catch((err)=> {
                err = new Error()
            })
        }
        
    useEffect(()=> {
            getAllMoviesData()
        }, [])

  return (
    <div className='home'>
        <div className="all-movies">
            {
               movieData ? movieData.map((movie, key)=> {return <MovieCard movie={movie} key={key} />}) : <div className="">Loading</div>
            }
        </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Home`
```

Comment: Instead of using a ternary operator, use conditional rendering -`{
               movieData.length > 0 && ( <MovieCard movie={movie} key={key} />) }`

Comment: The error likely happens in the `MovieCard` component, where you are trying to access a non-existent object property from the API.

Comment: Please try to replace MovieCard to a normal div. If not error, error should happens in MovieCard component. Also, you can use zod.ts object to check the data result.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I've tried conditional doesn't make a difference, Movie Card is fine as far as I'm aware, tried returning just a div still same issue. definitely to do with inside useEffect, the error appears and one second later it succeeds in doing the render with the data on page.